# How to run unit tests on an INSTALLED gcc installation

Tags: unit-testing, gcc, installation

I am unsure whether a version of GCC installed by my sys admin works correctly, as it gives me exotic errors. is it possible to test that installation (no, compiling a hello world is not enough)? Ideally I want to run the entire testsuite of gcc that I would run after installing it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a script in the GCC source tree to do this, see the file `contrib/test_installed`

You need DejaGnu and `expect` installed, because that's what the testsuite uses. But with those installed the script should do what you want. The comments in the file explain how to use it.